# AVCaptureSession Clean Up in Swift

Tags: pointers, swift, avcapturesession

I have a Swift project that's using AVCaptureSession to take photos within the app. I'm having difficulty getting the right syntax to properly clean up my objects. In Obj-C the suggested code would be as follows;

```
// Releases the object - used for late session cleanup
static void capture_cleanup(void* p)
{
    NewPostPreviewViewController* csc = (NewPostPreviewViewController*)p; 
    [csc release];  // releases capture session if dealloc is called
}

// Stops the capture - this stops the capture, and upon stopping completion releases self.
- (void)stopCapture {
    // Retain self, it will be released in capture_cleanup. This is to ensure cleanup is done properly,
    // without the object being released in the middle of it.
    [self retain];

    // Stop the session
    [session stopRunning];

    // Add cleanup code when dispatch queue end 
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", NULL);
    dispatch_set_context(queue, self);
    dispatch_set_finalizer_f(queue, capture_cleanup);
    [dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate: self queue: queue];
    dispatch_release(queue);
}
```

The finalizer would call `capture_cleanup` but I have no idea how to set the context or the pointer to the `capture_cleanup` function (or even what the function definition would look like)

So far I've tried the following but I'm not convinced I'm even on the right track;

```
let p: UnsafeMutablePointer<NewPostPreviewViewController> = UnsafeMutablePointer.alloc(sizeof(NewPostPreviewViewController))
p.initialize(self)

var videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", nil)
dispatch_set_context(videoDataOutputQueue, p)
dispatch_set_finalizer_f(videoDataOutputQueue, ????);
self.videoDataOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)
dispatch_release(videoDataOutputQueue)
```

Any help converting this would be most appreciated!

Comment: After spending many hours trying to figure this out I resorted to including a `CameraController.m` Objective-C class in my Swift project (with associated header) that I bridge to for access to the camera feed. The controller does all the work I need and stores the last image taken. It also produces a notification once the image is taken, allowing my Swift class to observe the notification and go get the last image taken... Not my ideal scenario but it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using bridging to Objective-C code. By including a CameraController.m Objective-C class in my Swift project (with associated header) I bridge for access to the camera feed.

The Objective-C class does all the work I need, and stores the last image taken. It also produces a notification once the image is taken, allowing my Swift class to observe the notification and go get the last image taken.